Why can I not intercept `write` in `seq`?
Based on Limit file IO speed I have built https://git.data.coop/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/iothrottle
It works for some programs:
iothrottle -i 10M cat foo > bar # Yes, here you could just use pv
iothrottle -o 1M ffmpeg -i foo.mp3 foo.wav
iothrottle -o 1M cp -a foodir /other/fs/foodir

This does not:
iothrottle -o 1M cp -a foodir /same/fs/foodir

because on the same file system cp uses a single call to copy_file_range per file.
I am OK with that limitation.
It also does not work for seq. When I run strace seq 100000 I get:
write(1, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14"..., 8192) = 8192
write(1, "\n1861\n1862\n1863\n1864\n1865\n1866\n1"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "2680\n2681\n2682\n2683\n2684\n2685\n26"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "499\n3500\n3501\n3502\n3503\n3504\n350"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "18\n4319\n4320\n4321\n4322\n4323\n4324"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "7\n5138\n5139\n5140\n5141\n5142\n5143\n"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "\n5957\n5958\n5959\n5960\n5961\n5962\n5"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "6776\n6777\n6778\n6779\n6780\n6781\n67"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "595\n7596\n7597\n7598\n7599\n7600\n760"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "14\n8415\n8416\n8417\n8418\n8419\n8420"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "3\n9234\n9235\n9236\n9237\n9238\n9239\n"..., 3838) = 3838

So it seems to call write (and not some mmap or other magic), and thus ought to work.
But when I run: IOTHROTTLE_DEBUG=1 iothrottle -o 1M  seq 10000 >/dev/null I get:
init called: default read_limit=0, write_limit=0
IOTHROTTLE_READ=0
IOTHROTTLE_WRITE=1048576
Final read_limit=0, write_limit=1048576
allowed: 608 written: 0
allowed: 617 written: 0

This tells me that iothrottle only intercepts 2 calls to write.
What am I missing?

strace shows you what system call are made, not what dynamic library function (the ones you can hijack) is called, for which you need ltrace instead.

In this instance, on my system, ltrace shows seq calling fwrite_unlocked which you're not wrapping.

YES! I never knew of ltrace. By intercepting fwrite_unlocked it works for seq.

Your iothrottle works by hijacking the functions of the C library that end up¹ doing system calls such as write(), pwrite() or splice()².
strace traces the system calls, not the dynamic library function calls, for which you need ltrace instead on GNU systems (ltrace can also trace system calls with -S; on other systems, equivalent commands such as truss or tusc (HP/UX) can also do both).
Here from zsh on Debian:
$ ltrace seq 10 |& grep -e{write,put,send}
fwrite_unlocked("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n", 21, 1, 0x7f5b1d7185c0) = 1

$ ltrace -S seq 10 |& grep -e{write,put,send}
fwrite_unlocked("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n", 21, 1, 0x7fe86c4785c0 <unfinished ...>
<... fwrite_unlocked resumed> )                  = 1
write@SYS(1, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n", 211

seq is calling the fwrite_unlocked() stdio function which you don't hijack, not fwrite() which explains why your iothrottle is not effective on it.
$ nm -uD  =seq | grep -e{write,put,send}
                 U fputc_unlocked@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fputs_unlocked@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fwrite@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fwrite_unlocked@GLIBC_2.2.5

Shows some of the -undefined -Dynamic symbols that seq needs (=seq can be written "$(command -v seq)" in other shells).
Calling seq with LD_DEBUG=bindings in the environment for the dynamic symbol showing information about what symbol is found where for whom can also help:
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/iothrottle.so IOTHROTTLE_WRITE=1000 LD_DEBUG=bindings seq 10  |& grep -e{write,put,send,iothrot}
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `init'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_pread'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_write'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_pwrite'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_copy_file_range'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_fwrite'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_writev'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_fflush'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_readv'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_sendfile'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_splice'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__cxa_finalize' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `original_read'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to seq [0]: normal symbol `stderr' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     14982: calling init: .../iothrottle.so
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `clock_gettime' [GLIBC_2.17]
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `getenv' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strtoull' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     14982: binding file seq [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `fwrite_unlocked' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     14982: binding file seq [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `fflush' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `dlsym' [GLIBC_2.34]
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `fflush'
     14982: binding file .../iothrottle.so [0] to .../iothrottle.so [0]: normal symbol `throttle'


¹ or may end-up like the stdio ones which often just fill up some buffers without doing any I/O until those buffers are flushed.
² BTW, there are more such as send(), sendto(), sendmsg() that can also do some I/O and more stdio functions that can end up doing some write()s such as fput(), putchar(), printf()....
